# Why Launch-VsDevShell.ps1 set my working directory to source\repos

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, powershell, visual-c++

**Why my working directory is modified by `Launch-VsDevShell.ps1` and how can we prevent this from happening?**

I'm writting a script building a C++ programm and I need MSVC on Windows.
MSVC tools (cl.exe, ...) are not definded in PATH by default and you need to execute [`Launch-VsDevShell.ps1`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/command-prompt-powershell?view=vs-2022#developer-powershell) to get this tools.
After executting `Launch-VsDevShell.ps1` in my script the current working directory is defined to `C:\Users\USERNAME\source\repos`.
I just want `Launch-VsDevShell.ps1` to add environement variable, not to change my pwd.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that command at all, but a quick google search indicates there's a `-SkipAutomaticLocation` switch you can use. Not sure if that'll be what stops it from changing your wd but, you can always modify the script yourself to prevent it from doing that. Apparently it invokes `Enter-VsDevShell` which may be the issue as well. I suggest just looking at the code/ps1 at changing it from there.

Comment: I can't modify the script because I use the one located on the user machine. But you are right and `-SkipAutomaticLocation` works. Tks !

Comment: I have an older version of that script installed, and looked at the code. Seems that `Enter-VsDevShell` is the culprit and has a `-StartInPath` parameter you can specify on where to switch the directory to. The default would be where the DLL is located. `Enter-VsDevShell @params -StartInPath (pwd).Path` was what I changed to make it not switch. Glad its been updated to include `-SkipAutomaticLocation` tho.

Comment: Hi ,glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider  accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `-SkipAutomaticLocation`

```
$vsWhere = "${Env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe"   
$vsInstallationPath = & $vsWhere -products * -latest -property installationPath
& "${vsInstallationPath}\Common7\Tools\Launch-VsDevShell.ps1" -Arch amd64 -SkipAutomaticLocation
```

Doc:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/command-prompt-powershell?view=vs-2022#skipautomaticlocation